# gVim puts extra <++> after sequence of "", $$, (), etc.

Tags: vim

I am using vim, and for some reason, it adds the phrase "<++>" after I write the sequences "", $$, (), [], {}, etc. 
I can't understand why this is the case or how I can solve it.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably writing latex files using the `vim-latexsuite` plugin. If so, this is the intended behavior; You can just press CTRL+J before a <++> mark to jump to it and remove it.

If that's not the case, please post more details; What version of gvim are you using, what files are you editing, and what plugins do you have installed?

Refer to the (imho rather scarily extensive) [documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/) for details.

Comment: I am. Why is this indended? What's its purpose?

Comment: @ido The purpose is to make writing latex easier. Example (cursor marked with `|`). If you write `$$|`, the expression gets expanded to `$|$<++>`. So now you're inside the math expression, can write there, and afterwards you can jump out with `C-j` without leaving insert mode. `((|` expands to `\left(|\right)<++>` which may be a more compelling example.

Comment: I didn't realize that. It indeed seems much easier. Thanks $\ddot\smile$